# Magento displaying base currency not default display currency

Tags: currency

I'm developing a site for a client which allows purchases to be made in one of 3 currencies: GB Pounds, Euros and US Dollars. However the client is based in the Arab Emirates and their bank account can only take transactions in AED (United Arab Emirates Dinari).

From what I've read, setting Magento up to do that should be easy: I've set the Base Currency as AED, the default display currency as GBP, and allowed currencies as GBP, USD, EUR and AED.

However, the website is only displaying prices in AED. I thought if I set the default display price as GBP then the website should display in GBP?
I'm using Magento CE 1.9.2.1 with a Payfort extension to provide the payment gateway.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong here?